# Delete all but the latest row per time period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to delete all rows except the latest in each period of time for a given interval.  For example, imagine I have a row for every day for two years, and I choose month as the given interval.  After deleting, I'd end with 24 rows, the last day of every month in those two years.  It's important that it's calendar aligned and not relative to the current date.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you provide table structures and an example of the output expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DELETE DataToBeDeleted 
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
     SomeDate, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Year(SomeDate), Month(SomeDate) 
                        ORDER BY SomeDate DESC) AS RankFromBack
   FROM DayData
) DataToBeDeleted
WHERE DataToBeDeleted.RankFromBack > 1;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f5f6/1)

For periods other than month, you'll need to adjust the partitioning and ordering to ensure that you rank the data that you want to retain accordingly.

Note that this also relies on deletion from a projection from a single table.